# Problems importing Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Dll into Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, sharepoint-2013, typelib

I am writing code to access Sharepoint for locating and opening files. My dev environment is Windows 10 64 bit and Delphi XE8.

I've downloaded and installed the SharePoint SDK (sharepointclientcomponents_15-4711-1001_x64_en-us.msi) and I am now trying to import microsoft.sharepoint.client and microsoft.sharepoint.client.runtime dll's using the Component > Import Component.. wizard.

When I try to import them as a .net assembly they are not in the initial list (probably because they are 64 bit and Delphi is only showing the GAC_32 directory) and when I click Add then select the DLL the dialog closes but nothing happens. The dll's are not in the list and there is no error message.

When I try to import as a TLB I get 'Error loading type library/DLL' and the detail of the error is not particularly helpful. The last three lines are:

```
[501B8578]{rtl220.bpl  } System.Win.ComObj.OleError (Line 1466, "System.Win.ComObj.pas" + 1) + $11
[21518467]{tlib220.bpl } TlbUtils.LoadTypeLibrary (Line 406, "TlbUtils.pas" + 11) + $2
[21518555]{tlib220.bpl } TlbUtils.LoadAndRegisterTypeLibrary (Line 429, "TlbUtils.pas" + 1) + $7
```

(let me know if you want the full error text posting).

I then tried RegASM:

```
regasm.exe Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll /tlb > Reg.log 2>&1
```

I repeated for the runtime dll and I was then able to successfully import the tlb's it generated into XE8. I also had to do the same for the 'mscorlib' and 'system' dll's to get it to compile.

So I now have my tlb's but they only appear to contain interface references and coclass creators. None of them have the properties and methods that should be there.

I have done lots of research and have seen questions on here about similar issues but they appear to be related to DLL's that do not expose their methods properly. I am assuming that the Microsft Sharepoint dll's that we are being told to use will have the correct implementation and therefore those answers do not apply.

This is also compounded by the fact that in Visual Studio/C# I can add a reference to the same dll's without having to resort to regasm, and all the properties and methods are present and correct. I can probably write a DLL in C# to expose the methods I want but I shouldn't have to resort to that should I?

I've chopped the Authentication and LoginResult entries from the runtime tlb as an example of how it looks in Delphi. The actual tlb is 2760 lines so a bit big to paste into here!

```
unit Microsoft_SharePoint_Client_Runtime_TLB;

// ************************************************************************ //
// WARNING
// -------
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from a
// Type Library. If this type library is explicitly or indirectly (via
// another type library referring to this type library) re-imported, or the
// 'Refresh' command of the Type Library Editor activated while editing the
// Type Library, the contents of this file will be regenerated and all
// manual modifications will be lost.
// ************************************************************************ //

// $Rev: 52393 $
// File generated on 28/04/2016 09:22:51 from Type Library described below.

// ************************************************************************  //
// Type Lib: c:\Temp\dllreg\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.tlb (1)
// LIBID: {439C353F-FFEE-349C-A9C6-4322906465F7}
// LCID: 0
// Helpfile:
// HelpString: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
// DepndLst:
//   (1) v2.0 stdole, (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb)
//   (2) v2.4 mscorlib, (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb)
//   (3) v2.4 System, (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.tlb)
// SYS_KIND: SYS_WIN32
// ************************************************************************ //
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF} // Unit must be compiled without type-checked pointers.
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
{$VARPROPSETTER ON}
{$ALIGN 4}

interface

uses Winapi.Windows, mscorlib_TLB, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Win.StdVCL, System_TLB, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.OleServer,
Winapi.ActiveX;


// *********************************************************************//
// GUIDS declared in the TypeLibrary. Following prefixes are used:
//   Type Libraries     : LIBID_xxxx
//   CoClasses          : CLASS_xxxx
//   DISPInterfaces     : DIID_xxxx
//   Non-DISP interfaces: IID_xxxx
// *********************************************************************//
const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  Microsoft_SharePoint_Client_RuntimeMajorVersion = 15;
  Microsoft_SharePoint_Client_RuntimeMinorVersion = 0;

  LIBID_Microsoft_SharePoint_Client_Runtime: TGUID = '{439C353F-FFEE-349C-A9C6-4322906465F7}';

  IID__Authentication: TGUID = '{FD87FC16-6D71-3F2A-ACCE-BCC193255B34}';
  IID__LoginResult: TGUID = '{D2AE246E-8C42-35EA-8EBF-2253EE2B1E54}';
...

  CLASS_Authentication: TGUID = '{94FE97EE-7E22-3F9B-AA69-2E9E9A428F19}';
  CLASS_LoginResult: TGUID = '{F8CDCD6E-DED5-3584-AEFE-C4AA74CDFF6D}';
...

// *********************************************************************//
// Forward declaration of types defined in TypeLibrary
// *********************************************************************//
  _Authentication = interface;
  _AuthenticationDisp = dispinterface;
  _LoginResult = interface;
  _LoginResultDisp = dispinterface;
...

// *********************************************************************//
// Declaration of CoClasses defined in Type Library
// (NOTE: Here we map each CoClass to its Default Interface)
// *********************************************************************//
  Authentication = _Authentication;
  LoginResult = _LoginResult;
...

// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: _Authentication
// Flags:     (4432) Hidden Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {FD87FC16-6D71-3F2A-ACCE-BCC193255B34}
// *********************************************************************//
  _Authentication = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{FD87FC16-6D71-3F2A-ACCE-BCC193255B34}']
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  _AuthenticationDisp
// Flags:     (4432) Hidden Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {FD87FC16-6D71-3F2A-ACCE-BCC193255B34}
// *********************************************************************//
  _AuthenticationDisp = dispinterface
    ['{FD87FC16-6D71-3F2A-ACCE-BCC193255B34}']
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: _LoginResult
// Flags:     (4432) Hidden Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {D2AE246E-8C42-35EA-8EBF-2253EE2B1E54}
// *********************************************************************//
  _LoginResult = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{D2AE246E-8C42-35EA-8EBF-2253EE2B1E54}']
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  _LoginResultDisp
// Flags:     (4432) Hidden Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {D2AE246E-8C42-35EA-8EBF-2253EE2B1E54}
// *********************************************************************//
  _LoginResultDisp = dispinterface
    ['{D2AE246E-8C42-35EA-8EBF-2253EE2B1E54}']
  end;
...

// *********************************************************************//
// The Class CoAuthentication provides a Create and CreateRemote method to
// create instances of the default interface _Authentication exposed by
// the CoClass Authentication. The functions are intended to be used by
// clients wishing to automate the CoClass objects exposed by the
// server of this typelibrary.
// *********************************************************************//
  CoAuthentication = class
    class function Create: _Authentication;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): _Authentication;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// The Class CoLoginResult provides a Create and CreateRemote method to
// create instances of the default interface _LoginResult exposed by
// the CoClass LoginResult. The functions are intended to be used by
// clients wishing to automate the CoClass objects exposed by the
// server of this typelibrary.
// *********************************************************************//
  CoLoginResult = class
    class function Create: _LoginResult;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): _LoginResult;
  end;
...

implementation

uses System.Win.ComObj;

class function CoAuthentication.Create: _Authentication;
begin
  Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_Authentication) as _Authentication;
end;

class function CoAuthentication.CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): _Authentication;
begin
  Result := CreateRemoteComObject(MachineName, CLASS_Authentication) as _Authentication;
end;

class function CoLoginResult.Create: _LoginResult;
begin
  Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_LoginResult) as _LoginResult;
end;

class function CoLoginResult.CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): _LoginResult;
begin
  Result := CreateRemoteComObject(MachineName, CLASS_LoginResult) as _LoginResult;
end;

...
end;
```

I suspect this may at least partially be a 32/64 bit issue, but I really have no idea.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: The IDE is 32-bit, so it's highly unlikely you can import a 64-bit COM library into it. You can use the library in your code at runtime (presuming you target Win64 as the platform), but if you want the components on the palette and available to drop onto forms you're going to need to use the 32-bit version of the library.

Comment: @Ken That's more or less what I suspected, thanks, but VS is also 32 bit and has no problem referencing and using the libraries?

Comment: I should also have said that I tried the 32 bit SDK but it won't install on a 64 bit system.